# FreePBX/Asterisk run script on call

Tags: php, asterisk

I'm fighting with this : I would call a php-script (which query a db and release a result) when I receive a call. 
I tried a lot of solution around but seems I'm not able to apply.

What I did :

I defined a custom extension (extension_custom.conf)

```
[myscript]
exten => 200,1,Answer()
exten=> 200,1,System(echo "${DATETIME} - ${CALLERID} - ${CHANNEL}" >> /var/log/asterisk/calls)
exten => h,1,Hangup()
```

I used this only for example obviously I would change System into

```
exten=> 200,1,System(/path/to/myphpscript.php ${CALLERID})
```

Now the problem is :
if I dial 200 from another extension i receive a "... call again later"

In which way I can execute the script on call (with or without answering)?

Thank you in advance ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You forget change priority.

```
exten => 200,1,Answer()
exten => 200,2,System(echo "${DATETIME} - ${CALLERID} - ${CHANNEL}" >> /var/log/asterisk/calls)
```